# Infinite loop when converting knockout object to plain JavaScript object

Tags: knockout.js

Folliwing instructions given in the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html), I have the following view model:

```
var newContactViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.Name = ko.observable();
    self.Address = ko.observable();
    self.City = ko.observable();
    self.State = ko.observable();
    self.PostalCode = ko.observable();

    self.Save = function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/contact",
            data: ko.toJS(self), //infinite loop here
            success: state.OnSaved
        });
    };
};
```

When the `self.Save` method is called, an infinite loop occurs. Chrome actually reports the error as:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

If I use `ko.mapping.toJS(self)` instead of `ko.toJS(self)`, then I get a slightly more revealing error, but no real error "message":

[image: infinite loop error]

If I swap `ko.toJS(self)` out with something like `{ Name: self.Name(), Address: self.Address() /* etc */ }`, then everything works fine. It seems like it's trying to convert the `Save` method and re-calling the method as a result.

There's either a bug in KnockoutJS or there's a problem when how I'm using it. I'd prefer the latter. Thoughts?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found out the problem with the code.  `ko.toJS` preserves functions in the object so it is able to map it fine.  However, jquery will invoke all functions on the data object to attempt to get a value.  This in turn causes the infinite loop.

You need to flag the `Save` function to not be mapped.  Unfortunately the `toJS` function doesn't appear to be able to do that.  It will keep all members of the object.  The mapping plugin fortunately allows you to do that.

To exclude a member, set the `ignore` option to an array containing `'Save'` and it will ignore the `Save` member when mapped.

```
var data = ko.mapping.toJS(self, {
    ignore: ['Save']
});
```

If you're not using the mapping plugin, you always have the option to remove the `Save` function from the JS object.

```
self.Save = function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/contact",
        data: self.ToData(),
        success: state.OnSaved
    });
};
self.ToData = function () {
    var data = ko.toJS(self);
    delete data.Save; // remove functions
    delete data.ToData;
    return data;
};
```

On the other hand, I would suggest not trying to use the view model instance as the data to your calls. I would explicitly create the data object instead. Sure it has the potential to be very long, but it's an approach that will very likely always work.

```
self.ToData = function () {
    return ko.toJS({
        Name: self.Name,
        Address: self.Address,
        City: self.City,
        State: self.State,
        PostalCode: self.PostalCode
    });
};
```

Comment: That's really useful information, because I was having trouble with Backbone models where I was adding a lot of references to parent collections etc. However, this is only a real solution, I think, if you're manually doing the conversion. It doesn't help if ko.toJS is used internally in other library code.

Comment: good solution to a completely disastrous design decision. what quite frankly makes me furious right now is that I didn't realize this behavior for months and it is essentially left as 'by design' https://github.com/knockout/knockout/pull/1079 - this needs to be configurable