# How can I make Knockout.js not invoke functions when I call ko.toJS()

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, to-json

I've been using knockout.js for months now and **only just** realized it invokes functions when calling `ko.toJS` when serializing my model.

This can lead to obvious problems like [infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12288603/infinite-loop-when-converting-knockout-object-to-plain-javascript-object), and at worst dangerous data corruption if a function with side effects is being called.

This behavior was at one point changed in an earlier version of Knockout, but it seems [it was backtracked upon](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/pull/1079) as being by design because sometimes some people want functions to be copied.

Well I never do (I don't think I do) and I'd really appreciate a way to be able to call `toJS` that would not invoke my functions.

I realize I can use `toJSON` instead but sometimes you really do want `toJS` in the case where you want to do something like this:

```
toJSON = () =>     // this is typescript syntax
{
     var copy = ko.toJS(this);

     // remove credit card details if not selected payment type
     if (this.paymentType() != 'CreditCard')
     {
         delete copy.creditCardDetails;
     }

     return copy;
}
```

Or perhaps I'm passing the model to some utility method that needs objects.

I guess I ultimately don't understand why the invocation of functions on my viewmodel isn't configurable and if there's an easy way to 'monkey patch' it or create a new `toJS2` function then I'd really like to be able to do that.

There is some very useful information in this question, [How can I use ko.toJs method without computed properties in knockout mapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673229/how-can-i-use-ko-tojs-method-without-computed-properties-in-knockout-mapping)  but as yet I've found no solution if I want to retain objects rather than convert to a string.

Comment: or perhaps some way to specify functions to ignore `_incrementQty()` with an underscore wouldn't get invoked

Answer (score 4):

For future reference (and I've encountered the same issue at times), you can create a mapping to ignore methods:

```
var mapping = {
    'ignore': ['load', 'reset', 'onSubmit']
};
var data = ko.mapping.toJS(object, mapping);
```

Comment: thanks. this is trickier when you have an object graph like I do - I construct 'objects' for each element in the viewmodel so when it is serialized there's a pretty complicated tree of functions and data

Comment: I must admit, I was frustrated that they'd "fixed" this then backtracked on it, but it is what it is at the moment!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was a false alarm.

While `toJS` does indeed retain the function references it was not Knockout itself that is invoking them.

I passed my data directly to jQuery's ajax function to make a POST request, and it was jQuery's JSON serialization which was actually causing the invocation..

If I passed `ko.toJSON(obj)` or even `JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(obj))` to jQuery then it worked fine.